# app.yaml depreciated for java in appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, yaml

Deploying using dev_appserver.sh required browser login every time. It is not updated for very long time. Is app.yaml base project depreciated in appengine java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the issue:

1/ the dev_appserver.sh is for running a local GAE SDK, not for doing app deployment.

2/ instead you should be using the appcfg.sh tools that is now defaulting to oauth2 so requirement the oauth dance the first time, then it reuses the locally cached tokens.

3/ for Java, you should not defined the app.yaml, it is automatically generated during a local staging phase from the web.xml and appengine-web.xml files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right. Somehow Intellij IDE is causing to refresh oauth. app.yaml is manually created where as web.xml and appengine-web.xml files are automatically generated. But my main question is should I migrated from using appcfg.sh to mvn?

Comment: Yes, this is not a supported case anymore. The correct process is to write web.xml and appengine-web.xml, and the appcfg tooling generates the correct app.yaml. Maven tool is great, but there is an updated Intellij plugin which is developed in the open source from Google that would also help a lot and improve the IDEA integration. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-intellij for progress.